# Create named PK when create table

Tags: postgresql, transaction, primary-key

I'm creating a table in Postgresql-11, and I need create a primary key for it at same time, to prevent from duplicated data being inserted before the PK created, so I want to these two operations be accomplished within a same transaction.

I know this can get it:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_tab (
    my_key INT8 NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( my_key ) );
```

But I want also set a name for this PK, instead of default name, in order to make the mantain works easy.

If I do it as following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_tab ( my_key INT8 NOT NULL );
ALTER TABLE my_tab ADD CONSTRAINT custom_pk_name_my_tab PRIMARY KEY ( my_key );
```

I'm worry about that these two statements will be done in two different tansactions. i.e. Is there any probability some duplicated data can be inserted before the PK created?

And further more, how about if the table existed already? If the tabe exists already, will the second statement get fail?

Above SQL is executed in my C++ program, that is a long-time daemon service.
I don't want it crash without human attended because of SQL failure.

How to get it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a constraint name both with the "column constraint syntax" and the "table constraint syntax" in `CREATE TABLE`:

```
CREATE TABLE my_tab (
    my_key INT8 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT my_tab_pkey PRIMARY KEY (my_key)
);
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE my_tab (
    my_key INT8
        CONSTRAINT my_tab_pkey PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Side remark: I'd avoid `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`. You can never be certain what you have got after the statement succeeds. There may have been a table with that name, but with wrong columns/owner/permissions/...

Comment: `CREATE IF NOT EXISTS` does not fail (issue an error) if the object with that name already exists. But that object could be something you don't expect at all, so be careful. There is absolutely no problem with dropping and re-creating tables, but for that you don't need `CREATE IF NOT EXISTS`, right` In that case, the preferable way is `DRP TABLE my_tab IF EXISTS;`, then `CREATE TABLE mytab`.

Comment: @Vérace No, that's all working as it should. The `CREATE TABLE` tag just signifies the successful completion of the statement. It ran successfully, even if it created nothing. (You'll also get an `INSERT` command tag if `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE`  updated a row.)

Comment: i.e. the `NOTICE` part succeeded, therefore the statement succeeded, even if it did nothing? You said that `But that object could be something you don't expect at all` - but the statement does nothing - as expected. Non-deterministic bug, or has it been fixed, or what's going on? BTW, I used 16beta - I can check with lower versions?

Comment: @Vérace That hasn't changed recently. The danger I meant is a different one: Perhaps there is already a table with that name, but it is different from what you expect. The existing relation could be a sequence or a view. Or it could have the wrong ownership. Or it could have been created by a malicious database user who knows that you will run `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` and wants to break your application or make it behave in ways it shouldn't.